# PostgreSQL group by date dynamic columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE public.conferimenti
(
    id smallint NOT NULL,
    datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    weight numeric(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    type smallint NOT NULL
)
```

like so

I want to get the SUM(weight) by every type grouped by day to build a timeseries chart with the best performance

```
SELECT c.datetime::date, SUM(weight) FROM conferimenti AS c
WHERE c.datetime >= '2019-01-01' AND c.datetime <= '2019-12-31' AND type = 1
GROUP BY c.datetime::date
```

This group by day but only type=1 .. i need for every type (there are 10-15 different types)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you only get type 1, it's part of the WHERE clause. Move it type to both select list and group by:

```
select c.datetime::date
     , c.type 
     , sum(weight) total_weight
  from c.conferimenti as c
 where c.datetime >= '2019-01-01' 
   and c.datetime <= '2019-12-31'  
 group by c.datetime::date, c.type;
```